# Getting Memory error while sorting pairs in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, struct, coredump

I am trying to sort pairs (`struct pairs { int i; int j; }` ) by the value of i. After sorting I would like to store the pairs according to which i has highest number of j's corresponding to it.
that is (1,3),(1,4),(2,5),(2,6),(2,7).
i have a structure els(int *i,int *j,int count),els[0] should have 2,5,,2,6,,2,7,,where 2's will be stored in i,5,6,7 in j.els[1] will have 1, its correspondings.
In the structure els when i am using pairs structure the code os running fine,but when i am going for two individual arrays i,j i am getting assert() coredumped error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct pairs
{
    int i;
    int j;
};
struct els
{
        int *i;
    int *j;
    int count;
};
void sortpairs(struct pairs *p,int count);
void sortj(struct pairs *p,int count);
void swapp(struct pairs *p,struct pairs *q);
int random(int min,int max);
int elina(int el,int arr[],int siz);

int main()
{
    struct pairs *pp = new struct pairs[10];
    srand(time(0));
    for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
    {
        pp[i].i = random(0,10);
        pp[i].j = random(0,10);
    }
    std::cout <<"BEFORE\n";
    for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
    {
        std::cout << pp[i].i <<"       "<<pp[i].j<<"\n";
    }
    sortj(pp,10);
    std::cout << "Done Sorting\n";
    std::cout <<"AFTER\n";
    for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
    {
        std::cout << pp[i].i <<"       "<<pp[i].j<<"\n";
    }
    sortpairs(pp,10);


    return 0;
}

void swapp(struct pairs *p,struct pairs *q)
{
    struct pairs temp;
    temp = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = temp;
}

int random(int min,int max)
{
    int n;
    n = rand()%(max - min) + min;
    return n;
}

int elina(int el,int arr[],int siz)
{
    for(int i = 0 ;i < siz;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == el)
            return i;
    }
    return -9;
}

void sortj(struct pairs *p,int count)
{
for(int i = 0 ; i < count - 1;i++)
    for(int j = i + 1;j < count;j++)
    {
        if(p[i].i > p[j].i)
            swapp(&p[i],&p[j]);
    }
}

void sortpairs(struct pairs *p,int count)
{
    int *arr = new int[count];
    int unqc = 0,az = 0,t;
    int  i;
    for(i = 0; i< count ;i++)
    {
        arr[i] = p[i].i;
        if(t = elina(arr[i],arr,i) < 0)
            unqc++;
    }
    az = i;
    std::cout <<"The Unique Elements are "<<unqc<<"\n";
    struct els *e = new struct els[unqc];
    int ec = 0;
    //e[0].i = new struct pairs[10];
    e[0].i = new int[10];
    e[0].j = new int[10];
    e[0].count = 0;
    for(int j = 0 ; j < count;j++)  
    {
        if(j > 0)
        {
            if(p[j].i == p[j-1].i)
            {
            //e[ec].p[count].i = p[j].i;
            //e[ec].p[count].j = p[j].j;
            e[ec].i[count] = p[j].i;
            e[ec].j[count] = p[j].j;
            e[ec].count++;
            }
            else
            {
            ec++;
            //e[ec].p = new struct pairs[10];
            e[ec].i = new int[10];
            e[ec].j = new int[10];
            e[ec].count = 0;
            //e[ec].p[count].i = p[j].i;
            //e[ec].p[count].j = p[j].j;
            e[ec].i[count] = p[j].i;
            e[ec].j[count] = p[j].j;
            e[ec].count++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //e[ec].p[count].i = p[j].i;
            //e[ec].p[count].j = p[j].j;
            e[ec].i[count] = p[j].i;
            e[ec].j[count] = p[j].j;
            e[ec].count++;
        }
    }
    for(int j = 0 ; j < unqc;j++)
    {
        std::cout << e[j].count <<"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: int *arr = new int[count];
    struct els *e = new struct els[unqc]; are not deleted. Every new should have delete

Comment: Are you limited to these data types? If not, I can recommend a solution using maps and lists/vectors that will get you the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In various places

```
        e[ec].i[count] = p[j].i;
        e[ec].j[count] = p[j].j;
```

should be

```
        e[ec].i[e[ec].count] = p[j].i;
        e[ec].j[e[ec].count] = p[j].j;
```

If you had used `std::vector` instead of `new` then you would have found this code easier to write, and it would have fewer bugs and limitations.

Comment: Thanks,Silly me to overlook that.